# How to fire validation on Save button in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

How do I fire validation on a Save button in Silverlight?

I am not using any data forms. I am using a RIA domain service for other operations but I want to validate everything on a save button before saving the data.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Silverlight_Validation_and_ViewModel.aspx) is something I've used to validate multiple things within a page before a save commits changes. You could also follow [Zoltan's blog](http://zoltanarvai.com/2011/04/14/mvvm-and-validation-at-mix11/) for a more complete structure. He's also presented at Mix '11 about this.